# Owin identity token authentication token endpoint responds with 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity, restful-authentication

I have been trying to add token based authorisation to my application using OWIN and asp.net identity and entity framework. However when I try to get my token through the token endpoint path I get a 404 response. My OWIN startup class:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Web.Startup))]

namespace Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("owin");
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<OwinAuthDbContext>(() => new OwinAuthDbContext());
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<UserManager<IdentityUser>>(CreateManager);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var provider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider();
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions option = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = false, //have also tried with true here
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = provider
            };
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(option);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        }

        private static UserManager<IdentityUser> CreateManager(IdentityFactoryOptions<UserManager<IdentityUser>> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>(context.Get<OwinAuthDbContext>());
            var owinManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
            return owinManager;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the token should be available under "/token", but when i call https://localhost:44373/token I get a 404 regardless of me adding headers for username, password and token_type. My OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider class:

```
public class MyAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        string clientId;
        string clientSecret;

        if (context.TryGetBasicCredentials(out clientId, out clientSecret))
        {
            // validate the client Id and secret against database or from configuration file.  
            context.Validated();
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_client", "Client credentials could not be retrieved from the Authorization header");
            context.Rejected();
        }
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
        IdentityUser user;
        try
        {
            user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Could not retrieve the user due to error.  
            context.SetError("server_error");
            context.Rejected();
            return;
        }
        if (user != null)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity identity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(
                                                    user,
                                                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Invalid User Id or password'");
            context.Rejected();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help.

**Edit:**

web.config dependent assembly:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Cors" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the config is actually hit while loading? Check that the NuGet package *Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb* is referenced.

Comment: The Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb package is referenced, when setting a breakpoint in the owin startup class it does not get hit. I think the entire startup class does not get executed but im not sure and I don't know why.

Comment: To make sure, the startup is only hit on the first call, not when you start to debug. Check your web.config to see if all dependentAssemblies are set, like Microsoft.Owin, Microsoft.Owin.Security, etc. And are you using the right port? http and https are different ports.

Comment: See edit for dependentAssemblies, I think this should all be correct. I'm using the correct port set in the properties of the web project, the rest of the project works fine, it loads my index.cshtml and all my api calls work fine.

Comment: Are you running in debug, IIS, IIS Express?

Comment: If you are running IIS please read this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/praburaj/2013/12/02/owin-startup-class-not-detected/

Comment: Tried with both local IIS and IIS Express both are not working, went through the steps in the link

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are passing in the **grant_type : password** too in your body and use POST to sent to http://localhost:XXXXX/token

- username : userXX
- password : XXXX
- grant_type : password

ps : I seeing that you are missing the `app.UseWebApi(config);` in your Configuration function? Please make sure it is called after `ConfigureOAuth(app);`

Example:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();   
            ConfigureOAuth(app);    
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

Comment: I have been sending these values but that is not what the problem is, sending a request without grant_type should return: invalid grant_type. However all I get returned is 404 not found. I also added `app.UseWebApi(config);` but it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}

private void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/Token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider()
    };

    //Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
}
```

**AuthorizationServerProvider.cs**

```
public class AuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();

        return base.ValidateClientAuthentication(context);
    }

    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        //Add parameters to token
        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));

        context.Validated(oAuthIdentity);

        return base.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your startup class is unreachable , Try to change the value of AutomaticAppStartup in Web.config to true as following :

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
.
.
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true" />
  <appSettings>
.
.
<configuration>
```